# Как реализовать корзину на сайт с двумя входными данными?

Tags: php

Ребята, помогите... Подскажите как сделать корзину с двумя входными данными: `$id`, `$sizeNumb`

Есть функция которая принимает `id` товара, а мне надо чтоб вместе с `id` принимал еще один параметр Размер товара `sizeNumb`:

Подскажите как реализовать, стоит ли использовать двумерные массивы?

вот функция:

```
//$id , $sizeNumb 

function addProduct($id){
  $id = intval($id);
  $productsInCart = array();

  if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $productsInCart = $_SESSION['products'];
  }

  if (array_key_exists($id, $productsInCart)) {
    $productsInCart[$id] ++;
  } else {
    $productsInCart[$id] = 1;
  }

  $_SESSION['products'] = $productsInCart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно хранить товарные позиции в двумерном массиве $productsInCart[$id][$sizeNumb] - первый индекс - идентификатор товара, второй - его артикул. Функция при этом может выглядеть примерно так

```
function addProduct($id, $sizeNumb){
  $id = intval($id);
  $productsInCart = array();

  if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $productsInCart = $_SESSION['products'];
  }

  if (!array_key_exists($id, $productsInCart)) {
    $productsInCart[$id] = array();
  }
  if (!array_key_exists($sizeNumb, $productsInCart[$i])) {
    $productsInCart[$id][$sizeNumb] = array();
  }
  $productsInCart[$id][$sizeNumb]++;

  $_SESSION['products'] = $productsInCart;
}
```

Comment: Функция конечно очень интересная...
вот его результат:
array(2){ 
  [7]=> array(2) { 
 ["count"]  => int(3) 
 ["sizeNumb"] => string(14) "96-100/170-176" 
  } 

  [9]=> array(2) { 
 ["count"]  => int(1) 
 ["sizeNumb"] => string(14) "96-100/182-188" 
  } 
} 

а мне нужно чтоб результат был как то так:

array(3){ 
  [7]=> array(2) { 
 ["count"]  => int(2) 
 ["sizeNumb"] => string(14) "96-100/170-176" 
  } 

  [7]=> array(2) { 
 ["count"]   => int(1) 
 ["sizeNumb"] => string(14) "88-92/182-189" 
  } 

  [9]=> array(2) { 
 ["count"]  => int(1) 
 ["sizeNumb"] => string(14) "96-100/182-188" 
  } 
}

Comment: У каждого id есть Размер товара sizeNumb, если оба параметра уже в массиве $productsInCart существует то увеличивается его количество, 
если id в массиве $productsInCart существует, а sizeNumb другой, то его то добавляет его как новый товар с count = 1. Вроде бы так (((((

Comment: @Rew, поправил ответ. Смотрите, у вас в желаемом массиве два поля с индексным ключом 7 - так не получится, придется менять ключ на строковый, например, "{$id}#{$sizeNumb}" (приведенный в ответе вариант), или, да придется использовать многомерные массивы.

Comment: "{$id}#{$sizeNumb}" если я так напишу то у меня не будет в базе такого товара... тоже не получается ... А как правильно тут с двумерными массивами работать... ? подскажи пожалуйста, че то у меня мозги уже высохли , весь день мучаюсь с этим

Comment: @Rew, поправил ответ.

Comment: Такую иерархию мне нужно получить array(2){ 
 [7]=> array(1) {  [96-100/170-176]=> array(1){ ["count"]  => int(2) } } 
 [7]=> array(1) {  [88-92/182-189]=> array(1) { ["count"] => int(1) } }
 [9]=> array(2) {  [96-100/182-188]=> array(1){ ["count"]  => int(5) } } 
}

Comment: вторая функция тоже не работает